# Bean Validation for @Past or today?

Tags: java, bean-validation

Here's a simple source, stating that this date must be in the past using Bean Validation :

```
@Past
private Date transactionDate;
```

Is there any BV annotation for validating that the date must be today or previous day?

Or perhaps I need to extend the constraint and provide my own?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just found out the answer for this, @Past means today or any day before today.

So, using @Past suits my need without having to provide my own constraint.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about that. Or at least it's not true anymore.
 
You have to use `@PastOrPresent` instead.

Comment: using @Past does not work for GET requests in Spring, any other methods for validating Date passed in a GET Method request

Answer (score 6):

To get past and today you can use

```
@PastOrPresent
```